# Extract the text using awk

Tags: awk, grep

I have the following information in input.txt file

```
<Host name="abc.net" type="Windows" bit="64" model="Virtual" configuration="Server" text="">
<Host name="def.net" type="Windows" bit="64" model="Virtual" configuration="Server" text="OSVersion:6.1,R2Enterprise,Processer:2">
```

I would need to extract only below details from the input.txt file with out the "" (double quotes), Can some one help me on that please ?

```
name="abc.net" model="Virtual" configuration="Server" text="">
name="def.net" model="Virtual" configuration="Server" text="OSVersion:6.1,R2Enterprise,Processer:2">
```

Comment: `awk '{print $2,$5,$6,$NF}' file` ?

Comment: No exactly what i am looking for. I need to exclude the double quotes and i need to match the text=""> and to show the full contents inside it.

Comment: for eg: name=abc.net  model=Virtual configuration=Server text=              name=def.net model=Virtual configuration=Server text=OSVersion:6.1,R2Enterprise,Processer:2

Comment: Post the actual output you expect then...

Comment: `awk '{print $2,$5,$6,$NF}' file | tr -d '">'`

Comment: You say you don't want double quotes but then your desired output includes double quotes. Please edit your question so the text and example match and if you truly don't want double quotes in the output then change your output to reflect that and be precisely what you want.

Comment: That looks like XML. If that is indeed the case, then the robust way to do this would be to parse the XML (SAX or DOM parser), then produce the desired textual output from that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what you want your output to look like, so I'll just print each field on a new line.

With Perl

```
perl -nE 'say join "\n", /(?:name|model|configuration|text)="\K(.*?)"/g' <<END
<Host name="abc.net" type="Windows" bit="64" model="Virtual" configuration="Server" text="">
<Host name="def.net" type="Windows" bit="64" model="Virtual" configuration="Server" text="OSVersion:6.1,R2Enterprise,Processer:2">
END
```

```
abc.net
Virtual
Server

def.net
Virtual
Server
OSVersion:6.1,R2Enterprise,Processer:2
```

With an XML parsing tool ([xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php)) -- requires valid XML input

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //Host -v @name -n -v @model -n -v @configuration -n -v @text -n <<END
<root>
<Host name="abc.net" type="Windows" bit="64" model="Virtual" configuration="Server" text="" />
<Host name="def.net" type="Windows" bit="64" model="Virtual" configuration="Server" text="OSVersion:6.1,R2Enterprise,Processer:2" />
</root>
END
```

```
abc.net
Virtual
Server

def.net
Virtual
Server
OSVersion:6.1,R2Enterprise,Processer:2
```

One advantage to the xmlstarlet answer is that it will render values with embedded quotes. If you have

```
text="with &quot;inner quotes&quot;"
```

Perl will output that as: `with &quot;inner quotes&quot;`
xmlstarlet will show you: `with "inner quotes"`

---

To use that output in a shell script:

```
perl ... | while read name; read model; read config; read text; do
    # do stuff with $name $model $config $text
    for var in name model config text; do
        printf "%s is: %s\n" "$var" "${!var}"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
cat file | egrep -o '"[^"]*"' | sed 's#"##g'
```